# Does mybatis-plus support upsert of postgresql

Tags: postgresql, mybatis, upsert

I am using this command to upsert data in PostgreSQL:

```
insert into sub_relation(user_id,sub_source_id,sub_status,created_time,updated_time)
    values (
      7,
      71,
      0,
      0,
      0
    )
    on conflict (user_id,sub_source_id)
    do update
    set sub_status=1;
```

in the database the sql running fine, but when I run this in my app when using MyBatis-Plus, it shows this error:

```
Caused by: com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.exceptions.MybatisPlusException: Failed to process, please exclude the tableName or statementId.
 Error SQL: insert into sub_relation(
      user_id,
    sub_source_id,
    sub_status,
    created_time,
    updated_time
    )
    values (
      ?,
      ?,
      ?,
      ?,
      ?
    )
    on conflict (user_id,sub_source_id)
    do update
    set sub_status=?;
    at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.toolkit.ExceptionUtils.mpe(ExceptionUtils.java:39) ~[mybatis-plus-core-3.2.0.jar!/:3.2.0]
    at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.parser.AbstractJsqlParser.parser(AbstractJsqlParser.java:74) ~[mybatis-plus-core-3.2.0.jar!/:3.2.0]
    at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.extension.handlers.AbstractSqlParserHandler.sqlParser(AbstractSqlParserHandler.java:76) ~[mybatis-plus-extension-3.2.0.jar!/:3.2.0]
    at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.extension.plugins.PaginationInterceptor.intercept(PaginationInterceptor.java:155) ~[mybatis-plus-extension-3.2.0.jar!/:3.2.0]
    at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Plugin.invoke(Plugin.java:61) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy168.prepare(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.prepareStatement(SimpleExecutor.java:87) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.doQuery(SimpleExecutor.java:62) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.queryFromDatabase(BaseExecutor.java:325) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.query(BaseExecutor.java:156) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Plugin.invoke(Plugin.java:63) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy167.query(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Plugin.invoke(Plugin.java:63) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy167.query(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Plugin.invoke(Plugin.java:63) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy167.query(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.github.pagehelper.PageInterceptor.intercept(PageInterceptor.java:111) ~[pagehelper-5.2.0.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Plugin.invoke(Plugin.java:61) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy167.query(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Invocation.proceed(Invocation.java:49) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at tk.mybatis.orderbyhelper.OrderByHelper.intercept(OrderByHelper.java:115) ~[orderby-helper-0.0.2.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Plugin.invoke(Plugin.java:61) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy167.query(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:147) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    ... 78 common frames omitted
Caused by: net.sf.jsqlparser.JSQLParserException: null
    at net.sf.jsqlparser.parser.CCJSqlParserUtil.parseStatements(CCJSqlParserUtil.java:128) ~[jsqlparser-2.1.jar!/:na]
    at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.parser.AbstractJsqlParser.parser(AbstractJsqlParser.java:60) ~[mybatis-plus-core-3.2.0.jar!/:3.2.0]
    ... 116 common frames omitted
Caused by: net.sf.jsqlparser.parser.ParseException: Encountered unexpected token: "conflict" <S_IDENTIFIER>
    at line 15, column 8.

Was expecting:

    "DUPLICATE"

    at net.sf.jsqlparser.parser.CCJSqlParser.generateParseException(CCJSqlParser.java:20951) ~[jsqlparser-2.1.jar!/:na]
    at net.sf.jsqlparser.parser.CCJSqlParser.jj_consume_token(CCJSqlParser.java:20798) ~[jsqlparser-2.1.jar!/:na]
    at net.sf.jsqlparser.parser.CCJSqlParser.Insert(CCJSqlParser.java:1648) ~[jsqlparser-2.1.jar!/:na]
    at net.sf.jsqlparser.parser.CCJSqlParser.SingleStatement(CCJSqlParser.java:132) ~[jsqlparser-2.1.jar!/:na]
    at net.sf.jsqlparser.parser.CCJSqlParser.Statements(CCJSqlParser.java:466) ~[jsqlparser-2.1.jar!/:na]
    at net.sf.jsqlparser.parser.CCJSqlParserUtil.parseStatements(CCJSqlParserUtil.java:126) ~[jsqlparser-2.1.jar!/:na]
    ... 117 common frames omitted
```

it seems the MyBatis-Plus not suport this, what should i do to make it work? by the way, this is my refence:

```
api "com.baomidou:mybatis-plus-boot-starter:3.4.0"
```

and this is my xml define:

```
<select id="upsert"
          parameterType="com.dolphin.soa.post.model.entity.SubRelation"
          resultType="java.lang.Integer">
    insert into sub_relation(
      user_id,
    sub_source_id,
    sub_status,
    created_time,
    updated_time
    )
    values (
      #{userId,jdbcType=BIGINT},
      #{subSourceId,jdbcType=BIGINT},
      #{subStatus,jdbcType=INTEGER},
      #{createdTime,jdbcType=BIGINT},
      #{updatedTime,jdbcType=BIGINT}
    )
    on conflict (user_id,sub_source_id)
    do update
    set sub_status=#{subStatus,jdbcType=INTEGER};
  </select>
```

this is the table DML:

```
CREATE TABLE public.sub_relation (
    id bigserial NOT NULL,
    user_id int8 NOT NULL,
    sub_source_id int8 NOT NULL,
    created_time int8 NOT NULL,
    updated_time int8 NOT NULL,
    sub_status int4 NULL,
    CONSTRAINT sub_relation_user_id_sub_source_id_key UNIQUE (user_id, sub_source_id)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

you should use  `<insert> ... </insert>`
replace your xml code:
 `<select> ... </select>`